# What is the correct order of form validation and retrieving input values?

Tags: laravel, validation

I wonder if I should do form validation before retrieving input values or vice versa.

I usually do validation first as I see no benefit in trying to access input values that might not be valid. However, a coworker looked at my code recently and found it strange. Is there any correct order for these steps?

```
public function createGroups(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'courses' => 'required_without:sections',
        'sections' => 'required_without:courses',
        'group_set_name' => 'required',
        'group_number' => 'required|integer|min:1'
    ]);

    $courses = $request->input('courses');
    $sections = $request->input('sections');
    $group_set_name = $request->input('group_set_name');
    $group_number = $request->input('group_number');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positioning the validation for your controller logic at the beginning of a method is *probably* the way to go here, as you have `required` parameters defined. If you receive data that does not fully satisfy the requirements, you produce a validation error back to the user. This follows the productive "Fail Fast" line of thinking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast

It's also important that you're not using any data that hasn't passed your stringent requirements from validation. Data that fails validation should no longer be trusted. Unless there's some other reason you need to be, say, logging any incoming data from the frontend, the order here looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with [@1000Nettles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54657586/7117697) response, to elaborate a little bit more on his/her answer (who should be the accepted one): There isn't any need to continue with your business logic when the data doens't comply with your specifications. Let's say you expected a string of a N characters long, because you defined your database with that limitation (in order to optimize the db desing), will you try to persist it even when it'll throw an exception? Not really.

Besides, Laravel has a particular way to extract validation classes: [Form Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation). This are injected in controllers. When a call reach the controller it means that already passed the validation, if not, an `422`error be returned.

Comment: Thank you @HCK. The link you provided to create form requests and the way it handles validation can help the controller be cleaner. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom request and keep the mess out of your controller, it doesn't even hit your controller function if validation failed and can just grab the data in your controller if validation passed.

`php artisan make:request GroupRequest`

In `app/Http/Requests/GroupRequest.php`:

```php
public function authorize()
{
    // return true;
    return request()->user()-isAdmin; // <-- example, but true if anyone can use this form
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'courses'        => ['required_without:sections'],
        'sections'       => ['required_without:courses'],
        'group_set_name' => ['required'],
        'group_number'   => ['required', 'integer', 'min:1'],
    ];
}
```

The best part is you can even manipulate the data in here (GroupRequest.php) after it has been validated:

```php
public function validated()
{
    $validated = $this->getValidatorInstance()->validate();

    // EXAMPLE: hash password here then just use new hashed password in controller
    $validated['password'] = Hash::make($validated['password']);

    return $validated;
}
```

In your controller:

```php
public function createUser(UserRequest $request) // <- in your case 'GroupRequest'
{
    $validated = $request->validated(); // <-- already passed validation

    $new_user = User::create($validated); // <-- password already hashed in $validated

    return view('dashboard.users.show')->with(compact('user'));
}
```

In your case, if you use my `GroupRequest` block above, you can return to view in 1 line of code:

```php
public function createGroups(GroupRequest $request)
{
    return view('example.groups.show')->with($request->validated()); // <-- already an array
}
```

In you blade view file, you can then use your variables like `{{ $group_set_name }}` and `{{ $group_number }}`